# Android device not seen in the choose list

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I want to use Nexus 7 for running my android app. I have enabled USB debugging and also checked for update of device driver but still the device is not shown in the choose list. I have tried all possibilities which were mentioned in other questions. Are there any other settings i need to change on my phone? Can anyone help me out because i have no idea why this is happening. Thanks

Comment: Have you turn on USB Debugging in Developer Options?

Comment: @BlackPearl you mean Usb debugging right? Yes i have done that.

Comment: You need to check this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: Did the computer recognise your device?

Comment: @hmartinezd i have done that too.

Comment: @BlackPearl my computer recognises it with success

Comment: Does it show `USB debugging connected` on the notification bar at the top?

Comment: @BlackPearl yes it does

Comment: remove it and try it again, or better still reset your phone or restart your IDE.

Comment: @BlackPearl i removed it several times even restarted eclipse and also my computer. I cant reset my phone.

Comment: try Reset ADB also From DDMS>Devices

Comment: @BlackPearl i cant see Reset ADB option in DDMS>devices

Comment: You using Windows? If yes, right click on the `Task Bar`, click on `Start Task Manager`, click on the `Processes` Tab, check for `adb.exe` on the box under `Image Name`, right click on it and click `End process tree`

Comment: @BlackPearl that didnt help too

Comment: Why don't you wanna reset your phone?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what you mean by **can't show in the choose list** but you need to `run` the app first with your phone connected to your computer. This is what you get

[image]

You can see my device in the first option to choose from.If you don't see this, try restarting the phone and your computer.

Comment: Exactly i am not able to see my device. That is my problem

Comment: Have you tried restarting both the phone and computer?